# Where can I find a list of features in Magento along with explanations?

Tags: magento2, documentation, resources, features

For example, this link: https://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/magento-feature-list.pdf - has a great list of features, but without any explanation of what that feature is about.

For example, on page 2 of 10, what does "Minimum Advertised Price (MAP)" mean?  I'm looking for a resource which gives a 2-3 line description of what that feature is all about. Somethings are self-explanatory, but most could use some elaboration.

Comment: if your products have tier prices with discount for volume i.e. buy 5 save % then minimum advertised price will display the lowest price for that product.

Comment: I think you will just have take what's in the pdf and use the search feature on the user guide and cross reference them yourself eg https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-minimum-advertised-configure.html?itm_source=merchdocs_ce&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=Map